# Replacing values with groupby means

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame with a column that has some bad data with various negative values. I would like to replace values < 0 with the mean of the group that they are in.

For missing values as NAs, I would do:

```
data = df.groupby(['GroupID']).column
data.transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
```

But how to do this operation on a condition like `x < 0`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using @AndyHayden's example, you could use `groupby`/`transform` with `replace`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1],[1,-1],[2,1],[2,2]], columns=list('ab'))
print(df)
#    a  b
# 0  1  1
# 1  1 -1
# 2  2  1
# 3  2  2

data = df.groupby(['a'])
def replace(group):
    mask = group<0
    # Select those values where it is < 0, and replace
    # them with the mean of the values which are not < 0.
    group[mask] = group[~mask].mean()
    return group
print(data.transform(replace))
#    b
# 0  1
# 1  1
# 2  1
# 3  2
```

Comment: I was thinking something similar -- `.transform(lambda x: x.where(x>=0).fillna(x[x>=0].mean()))` but didn't like the repetition of the condition.   Your approach bypasses that nicely.  The pattern seems common enough that I wonder if `pandas` should grow a built-in way to support it.

Comment: @DSM I agree it would be nice to see some way to do this (this numpy-foo is impressive!) :)

Comment: very nice. I haven't seen the use of [~mask] - does the tilda just mean `not mask`?

Comment: @zach: `mask` is a `Series`, which is a subclass of numpy's `ndarray` class. The tilde is the [invert operator](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.invert.html#numpy.invert) when applied to a numpy ndarray. Since `mask` is of dtype `bool` (i.e. a boolean array) the inversion is done bit-wise for each element in the array. `not mask` has a different meaning. This asks Python to reduce `mask` to its boolean value as a whole object and then take the negation. Numpy arrays refuse to be characterized as True or False. `not mask` raises a `ValueError`.

Comment: Word of warning: Your custom function should not modify the group in-place. It should make a copy, and modify that instead. See https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html

Comment: What does the ~ sign mean in front of the mask parameter?

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to do it (for the `'b'` column, in this boring example):

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1],[1,-1],[2,1],[2,2]], columns=list('ab'))
In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
   a  b
0  1  1
1  1 -1
2  2  1
3  2  2
```

Replace those negative values with NaN, and then calculate the mean (`b`) in each group:

```
In [3]: df['b'] = df.b.apply(lambda x: x if x>=0 else pd.np.nan)
In [4]: m = df.groupby('a').mean().b
```

Then use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) across each row, to replace each NaN with its groups mean:

```
In [5]: df['b'] = df.apply(lambda row: m[row['a']]
                                       if pd.isnull(row['b'])
                                       else row['b'],
                           axis=1) 
In [6]: df
Out[6]: 
   a  b
0  1  1
1  1  1
2  2  1
3  2  2
```

Comment: I see, by applying that lambda function I can make them nans! Then couldn't I just use the `.fillna` line I wrote in my question? Your second `.apply` seems unnecessary.

Comment: @Def_Os I couldn't get that line to work for me, but perhaps that is a better way :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and came up with a rather simple solution

```
func = lambda x : np.where(x < 0, x.mean(), x)

df['Bad_Column'].transform(func)
```

Note that if you want to return the mean of the correct values (mean based on positive values only)  you'd have to specify:

```
func = lambda x : np.where(x < 0, x.mask(x < 0).mean(), x)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a great Example, for your additional question.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1, 1, 2, 2], 'B' : [1, -1, 1, 2]})
gb = df.groupby('A')
def replace(g):
   mask = g < 0
   g.loc[mask] = g[~mask].mean()
   return g
gb.transform(replace)
```

Link: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html

Comment: Ahh, I understand.  Your answer doesn't generalize to to more complicated dataframes.  Doesn't matter, very smart!  I'm going to continue playing around.